# Launchd plist cannot load

Tags: macos, plist, launchd

I am playing around with a very simple plist script which I want to execute at start-up and should create a simple text document after execution.

The file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd";>
  <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.info.test.agent</string>
    <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
    <string>Background</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
     <string>/usr/bin/touch</string>
     <string>/Users/foobar/Desktop/TestAgentDidRun.txt</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
   </dict>
  </plist>
```

After saving I then try to load it:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.info.test.agent.plist
```

The response I get is: Service cannot load in requested session.

I'm running Mac OS 10.15.7 - Catalina.

Any ideas?

Comment: `launchctl load` works when `LimitLoadToSessionType` is `Aqua`, but not for `Background`.

Answer (score 1):

Using your plist example, here's how to start/stop it:

- load: `sudo launchctl bootstrap user/UID ~/Library/LaunchAgents/background_touch.plist`
- unload: `sudo launchctl bootout user/UID ~/Library/LaunchAgents/background_touch.plist`

Get UID by running commandline: `id -u`

Comment: I tried your command, but it throws an error:

/Users/<my-user-name>/Library/LaunchAgents/com.manager.p.plist: Service cannot load in requested session
Bootstrap failed: 134: Unknown error: 134

Comment: @Willis But if I put the plist file to /Library/LaunchAgents/, it works. but I don't know why not working if the plist file if in  ~/Library/LaunchAgents/

Comment: @Willis I changed `user/UID` to `gui/UID`, now it works fine.

Comment: @Willis  Glad you got it working!  Thanks for sharing your edit to make it work.